# Why is my string getting modified inside this code?

Tags: c++, string

I am taking an integer as input in a string that is string s. I want to write integer in s in the form of "-"'s and "|". I am sure that my logic is right. The problem is string s is automatically getting modified inside the code. When I initially print the string s, it returns complete 12345 (My input is "2 12345") but when I tries to print it afterwards it is getting truncated or something. How do I resolve this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n;
    std::string s;
    cin >> n;
    cin >> s;
    cout << s.at(3) <<endl;
    while(n!=0){
        for (int l=0;l<3+2*n;l++){
            //  for (int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
            if (l==0){
                for (int j=0;j<s.length();j++){
                    if (s.at(j)=='1'||s.at(j)=='4'){
                        cout << " ";
                        for (int k=0;k<n;k++){
                            cout << " ";
                        }
                        cout << " ";
                    }
                    else if (s.at(j)=='0'||s.at(j)=='2'||s.at(j)=='3'||s.at(j)=='5'||s.at(j)=='6'||s.at(j)=='7'||s.at(j)=='8'||s.at(j)=='9'){
                        cout << " ";
                        for (int k=0;k<n;k++){
                            cout << "-";
                        }
                        cout << " ";
                    }
                    cout << " ";
                } 
            }

            else if (l==n+1){
                for (int j=0;j<s.length();j++){
                    if (s.at(j)=='1'||s.at(j)=='7'||s.at(j)=='0'){
                        cout << " ";
                        for (int k=0;k<n;k++){
                            cout << " ";
                        }
                        cout << " ";

                    }
                    else if (s.at(j)=='2'||s.at(j)=='3'||s.at(j)=='4'||s.at(j)=='5'||s.at(j)=='6'||s.at(j)=='8'||s.at(j)=='9'){
                        cout << " ";
                        for (int k=0;k<n;k++){
                            cout << "-";

                        }
                        cout << " ";
                    }
                    cout << " ";
                }
            }
            else if (l==2*n+2){
                for (int j=0;j<s.length();j++){
                    if (s.at(j)=='1'||s.at(j)=='4'||s.at(j)=='7'){
                        cout << " ";
                        for (int k=0;k<n;k++){
                            cout << " ";
                        }
                        cout << " ";
                    }
                    else if (s.at(j)=='0'||s.at(j)=='2'||s.at(j)=='3'||s.at(j)=='6'||s.at(j)=='8'||s.at(j)=='9'||s.at(j)=='5'){
                        cout << " ";
                        for (int k=0;k<n;k++){
                            cout << "-";
                        }
                        cout << " ";
                    }
                    cout << " ";
                }
            }
            else if ((l>0) && (l<n+1)){
                for (int j=0;j<s.length();j++){
                    if (s.at(j)=='1'||s.at(j)=='2'||s.at(j)=='3'||s.at(j)=='7'){
                        cout << " ";
                        for (int k=0;k<n;k++){
                            cout << " ";
                        }
                        cout << "|";
                    }
                    else if(s.at(j)='4'||s.at(j)=='8'||s.at(j)=='9'||s.at(j)=='0') {
                        cout << "|";
                        cout << "s "<< s<< endl;
                        cout << "check 2";
                        for (int k=0;k<n;k++){
                            cout << " ";
                        }
                        cout << "|";
                    }
                    else if(s.at(j)=='5'||s.at(j)=='6'){
                        cout << "|";
                        cout << "check";
                        for (int k=0;k<n;k++){
                            cout <<" ";
                        }
                        cout << " ";

                    }
                    cout << " ";
                }
            }
            else if ((l>n+1) && (l<2*n+2)){
                for (int j=0;j<s.length();j++){
                    if (s.at(j)=='1'||s.at(j)=='3'||s.at(j)=='5'||s.at(j)=='7'||s.at(j)=='9'||s.at(j)=='4'){
                        cout << " ";
                        for (int k=0;k<n;k++){
                            cout << " ";
                        }
                        cout << "|";
                    }
                    else if(s.at(j)='6'||s.at(j)=='8'||s.at(j)=='0') {
                        cout << "|";
                        for (int k=0;k<n;k++){
                            cout << " ";
                        }
                        cout << "|";
                    }
                    else if(s.at(j)=='2'){
                        cout << "|";
                        for (int k=0;k<n;k++){
                            cout <<" ";
                        }
                        cout << " ";
                    }
                    cout << " ";
                }
            }
            cout << s << endl;
            cout << endl;
}
            cin >> n;
            cin >> s;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code to see which line is modifying the string unintentionally?

Comment: It's no wonder you have problems. Where are the program comments?

Comment: I'm not sure what your code is trying to do, but I see this: `s.at(j)='4'` `s.at(j)='6'`

Comment: Turn warnings on and fix any you get... For gcc: -Wall -Wextra

Comment: @Tawnos nails it: take care with = and ==. But this is bad code: so unreadable. That's why errors have crept in.

Comment: Use a `const` variable if you want to ensure immutability, the compiler will throw an error where you break the `const` rule.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A quick look reveals that `s.at(j)='6'` and `s.at(j)='4'` modify your string. You can avoid this by using [Yoda Conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_Conditions).

There are compilers that may warn you about an assignment, here. (See comments).

Also see Mats Petersson's answer, which I consider to be the best adivce: Use const objects, references or pointers to const memory if you do not want to alter contents in a certain situation.

If you'd use a function that takes a `std::string const &s` for it's argument, doing the job, you'd end up having

- cleaner code structure and
- compiler errors upon alteration of your argument `s`.

Comment: Better use `-Wall` option (I didn't downvoted).

Comment: @Pixelchemist Nice nickname.  Never heard of Yoda Conditions.

Comment: Please don't promote Yoda Conditions. All recent compilers that have a little bit of self respect should give you a nice warning. OP: Use '-Wall -Wextra -Werror' and make it compile :)

Comment: I didn't downvote either but Yoda conditions indeed suck.

Comment: The OP's logic errors can be avoided using Yodas. I don't use them for myself but I also don't want to give an eassy about pros and cons here. The best advice to avoid the problem is Mats' answer anyway.

Comment: @Pixelchemist From my 20 years of experience, I'd say they produce more bugs by messing up the developer's brain than preventing bugs. Code as clear as possible should be! ;-P

Answer (score 10):

`else if(s.at(j)='4'||`

You forgot an = sign.

Answer (score 9):

If you have a situation where you want to avoid unintentionally modifying a variable (for example a string), you can either break out the relevant code into a function and pass a `const string& x` to the function, or you can create a local const reference. In your code, one could do:

```
std::string ms;
cin >> n;
cin >> ms;
const &std::string s = ms;
```

Now you will get an error any time you try to make changes to `s`, because it's a `const`.

Comment: Wanted to post that answer ;) Using `const` makes everything clear and will help you to avoid such problems at the very start.

Comment: +1 Few weeks ago, somewhere in the comments, there was a user that was suggesting OP to replace `const int` with `#define` with statement: `Thank you for your answer, but i don't need to protect my code from myself. If the only reason for you to use const int instead of #define value is basically to limit the freedom of the programmer then no thank you, i'm sticking with preprocessor.`

Comment: @NemanjaBoric: Well, there is no helping some people. And some programmers really do need help protecting themselves from their own mistakes (and at times, even after nearly 30 years of working as a programmer, I do need that help too - I'm just more aware of my own fallibility than some beginners, I suppose).